# filter specific string in R

Tags: r, string, tidyverse

I would like to get names with `sp.`, `sp.` , and `sp`, and remove the `"Antidesma cuspidatum"`

```r
df <- data.frame(name1 = c("Acranthera sp. 01", "Amydrium sp.01", "Alyxia sp.", "Antidesmatoideae sp.", "Antidesma cuspidatum"))
```

I am using `filter_at` but `"Antidesma cuspidatum"` still included since it contains `sp`

```r
df %>% 
  filter_at(.vars = vars(name1), all_vars(grepl("sp.|sp. ",.)))
```

```
                 name1
1    Acranthera sp. 01
2       Amydrium sp.01
3           Alyxia sp.
4  Antidesmatoideae sp.
5 Antidesma cuspidatum
```

Any suggestions for me?

My desired output

```
                 name1
1    Acranthera sp. 01
2       Amydrium sp.01
3           Alyxia sp.
4 Antidesmatoideae sp.
```

Comment: Do you need `df %>% filter(grepl('sp.', name1, fixed = TRUE))` ? why `Antidesmatoideae sp.` is not there in the output ?

Comment: sr, my mistake i will edit my questiom